# Kolmogorov continuity criterion

Tags: probability-theory

Kolmogorov's continuity criterion states that, suppose $X=\{X_t,0\leq t\leq1\}$ is a real-valued stochastic process, and if there are constants $a,b,K>0$ such that for all $s,t\in[0,1]$ we have $$E|X_s-X_t|^a\leq K|s-t|^{1+b},$$ then there is a modification of $X$ with continous sample path (for almost every $\omega$).

The key step to prove this theorem is the following lemma,which is purely determistic:

Lemma: let $D$ be the set of dyadic raionals in $[0,1]$ and $X$ a function defined on $D$. If there are constants $C,\gamma>0$ such that $$\sup_{n\geq1}\max_{1\leq k\leq 2^n}\frac{|X_{k/2^n}-X_{(k-1)/2^n}|}{2^{-\gamma n}}= C<\infty,$$ then $X$ is $\gamma-$ Holder continuous on $D$.

My own proof of this lemma is quite different from the expositions in text books, it's quite nead and short than other proofs I've seen, so I wonder if there is something wrong in my argument.

It goes as follows:

suppose $s,t\in D$, then we can find integer $m$ so that $s,t\in D_m$, where $D_m$ is the $m-$th level of dyadic rationals:$D_m=\{k/2^m|k=0,1,\ldots,2^m\}$. Then $\{s,s+\frac{1}{2^m},\ldots,t-\frac{1}{2^m},t\}$ are points with equal distance $1/2^m$, and they divide $[s,t]$ into $\frac{t-s}{2^m}$ small intervals.so
\begin{align*}|X_t-X_s|&\leq |X_s-X_{s+\frac{1}{2^m}}|+\cdots+|X_{t-\frac{1}{2^m}}-X_t|\\&\leq C2^{-\gamma m}(\frac{t-s}{2^m})\\&\leq C(t-s).\end{align*}
Here we used the fact $\gamma>0$ and $m\geq0$. so $X$ is uniformly continous on $D$.

I confess this estimation can only proof the uniform continous part of $X$, not the $\gamma$-Holder continous. But this is suffice to deduce the Kolmogorov continuity theorem. Is there something wrong?

By the way, the standard proof of the lemma is still mysterious to me, can anyone explain the idea to me? I'll be grateful for your reply.

Comment: The interval $(s,t)$ is divided into $(t-s)2^m$ intervals of length $1/2^m$, not into $(t-s)/2^m$ of them. This kills your approach when $\gamma\lt1$ (which is the case of interest).

Comment: @Did:Thanks, this is my mistake.